# why does sum price*quatity does not work?

Tags: mysql, sql

6. What is the SQL code for this query?

"Give me the contact info for the top 5 customers who spent the most money. Include the email, phone number, and total amount spent."

Note: One customer can have multiple orders, so please sum across orders.

my code:

```
SELECT
    TOP 5 email,
    phone,
    SUM(Price * Quantity)
FROM
    Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id
GROUP BY
    Customers.customer_id
ORDER BY
    SUM(Price * Quantity)
DESC
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: MySQL does not support `select top`.

Comment: So what is the problem?  Do you get a syntax error?  Or are the results not correct?

Comment: Please share the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output data for your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT
    email,
    phone,
    SUM(Price * Quantity)
FROM
    Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.customer_id = Orders.customer_id
GROUP BY
    Customers.customer_id
ORDER BY
    SUM(Price * Quantity)
DESC
LIMIT BY 5
```

MySQL syntax is a little different than MSSQL. TOP = LIMIT and it goes to the end rather being at the top of the query